# How to produce documents like factset blackline?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks

Factset blackline reports essentially can compare two [10-Q SEC filings](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10q.asp) and show you the difference between the two documents. It highlights added items in green and removed items in red + strikethrough (essentially, it's a document difference, but longer-term I would like to run algorithms on the differences).

I don't care to change colors, but what I would like to do is to produce similar extracts that summarize addition and deletions.

Which AI/ML algorithm could do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Financial information companies spend a very large amount of effort to do this kind of thing properly, and their models are generally proprietary, so the real answer is not something you'll be able to get on a public site.

Of course, you can achieve a very simple approximation with a literal diff on the texts, and a more sophisticated one by using out-of-the-box NLP or computer vision techniques, but you're probably not going to get close to the performance of factset or other competitors using those tools.